# Is there momentum conservation in photoelectric emission?

Tags: momentum, conservation-laws, photoelectric-effect

There is actually a question in my textbook which I am unable to understand.I didn't understand anything

[image: Question]

Comment: The question in the photograph is ungrammatical and does not mean anything in English, unfortunately. This is irresponsible and abusive - but as the victim there is not much you can do about it.

Comment: Yeah I didn't understand what they said

Comment: Before considering metal as a whole, you may want to look at [scattering of light with single electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering). You will find that electrons don't have momentum in the same direction as incident photon (and it follows from energy-momentum conservation). Inside a metal, there are multiple scatterings with electrons/nuclues , however, the qualitative argument remains the same - energy/momentum is conserved as a whole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The excerpt is trying to make the following point, in a muddled way:

> In the photoelectric effect, the electrons are emitted in a different direction than the incident photons. Doesn't this violate conservation of momentum? How do we reconcile this?

> The momentum of the system as a whole is conserved, but the system includes the nuclei and other electrons remaining in the metal.  The incoming momentum ends up in the metal itself.

(To which I would add that the metal also experiences a slight recoil due to the ejection of the emitted electron. But as with the incident photon momentum, this effect is negligible.)